# Activation error when installing a bundle in OSGi

Tags: osgi

I am getting the following error when installing a bundle.

```
Failed to start bundle x.y.z-1.0.0, exception activator error    org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator from: java.lang.ClassLoader:defineClass1#-2
```

How can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get rid of the message would be to not install the bundle :-)

It sounds like the bundle's activator class depends on a class the bundle cannot load. So perhaps the desired class was not properly packaged in the bundle or the necessary import package clause is missing.

Comment: Ya, what you said was right. I packaged the desired classes and got rid of it. Thank you BJ.